# Considerations while creating Managed Package

Tags: managed-package

I am trying to develop managed package and giving it to Client so that Client installs in their Production org. The managed Package that we trying to create handles updation in the fields. As fields of clients need to update, I am trying to create object which looksup to Account object and using operation we are updating.
Please let me know what are the considerations while creating Managed Package. If I go with this route, What will be the limitations that I can come across.

Answer (score 1):

Managed packages are a great way to deploy your app to your customers. There are several things to take into account:

- Whenever you create a managed package, your code (ie: Apex classes and triggers) is hidden, but your Visualforce components are visible.
- If you want to expose an API to be called by your customer's code, you need to make the classes `global` so that they can be called from outside the package
- Some components are 'locked in' and cannot be removed or updated. In particular, any `global` class is locked in, so think well before adding a global class to your package. There is more information here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm
- The debug statements in your managed package are not visible in your customer's org. They are only visible inside the LMA (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/). I would suggest installing the LMA on your package org before any customer installs the pacakge, so that you can track all the installations.

I'm sure there are many more, but those are the main concerns I have when creating a managed package. Overall, managed packages are a good way to distribute code, but you just need to be a bit careful about what to include in them.